# Utilities.sleep not running as expected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below script which was running but after adding the `utilities.sleep` and app flush function it isn't.  Can anyone see what I did wrong? When the "nameofspreadsheet" runs it takes a few seconds for the script to run and put the correct sheetname in A2, taken from the workbook name. So this means the backup script runs but enters date 01/01/1970 in the archive sheet instead of the date the sheet was used (I make multiple copies maybe months in advance so only need it to backup on the day it is used).

```
function onOpen() { // This function adds a custom menu to the spreadsheet (Backup to archive) so you can run the script from there.
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Backup')
    .addItem('Backup','dataBackup')
    .addToUi();
}

function nameOfSpreadsheet()
{
    var s=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName().replace(/(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}).*/,
'$1');
    return s;
}

function dataBackup() {
    var inputSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var archiveSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('146WU8RghfFqlCpCSX7n6kBAKOyxcpVKt14yhVfvYz-g');
    var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var sheetNames = ['AM trip', 'PM trip', 'Pool / Beach', 'Night Dive'];
    for (var i = 0; i < sheetNames.length; i++) {

        var inputSheet = inputSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);
        var archiveSheet = archiveSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);

        var date = inputSheet.getRange('A2').getValue(); // Changed to stop inadvertent cell changes, also made text white so not seen.
        var data = inputSheet.getRange('E7:U37').getValues().filter(function(row) { return row[0] !== '' || row[1] !== ''});

        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
            data[x].splice(0, 0, date);
        }
        var getDate = archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValue();
        var maxRowLength = data.reduce(function(length, row) { return Math.max(length, row.length); }, 0);
        var date = new Date(date); 

        if (date.getDate() === "Loading Data...") {
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

            if (getDate.getDate() != date.getDate() || getDate.getMonth() != date.getMonth()) {     

                if (data.length != 0) {
                    archiveSheet.insertRowsAfter(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), data.length);
                    archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, maxRowLength).setValues(data);
                } else {
                    archiveSheet.insertRowsAfter(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 1);
                    archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 2).setValues([[date, 'No Data']]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the wrong date turning up? You code seems to work for adding the correct date to the head of the data row, so where do you see the zero date output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date.getDate() === "Loading Data..."` always will be false and the true from if will never be executed because just above the script has the following line

```
var date = new Date(date);
```

This line assigns a datetime to `date` that so date.getDate(date) could return an integer if `date` is a valid argument. By the way, usually it's better to reuse variable names and to use variable names that they spelling / writing is similar to keywords because this could lead certain programmers to be confused.

date.getDate() will never return "Loading Data..." as this string it's not part of the JavaScript specification but it's from Google Sheets.

Considering the above the problem isn't Utilities.sleep().

If you fear that

```
var date = inputSheet.getRange('A2').getValue();
```

could return "Loading Data..." the Utilities.sleep(milliseconds) should be included before that line.

Regarding SpreadsheetApp.flush() it should be included after the script made important changes to the spreadsheet. Its place on your code could be at the end of the for block but maybe it could be better to rethink the logic of the OP script.